# Global.asax.cs events not firing after website publish

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I've been looking around online for an answer to this for hours, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

I have a WebSite in VS 2010 (.Net 4.0 framework, C #) that has a Global.asax file in the root directory and a Global.asax.cs file in the App_Code folder.  (Note that this is a WebSite, not a web application).  When running this WebSite from my local development machine, everything runs as expected - more specifically the Session_Start event in the Global.asax.cs file fires and runs some code at the start of every session to get the user's logon credentials, which determine what they are allowed to see/edit in the application based on their security level.

However, once I publish this WebSite onto a Windows 2003 R2 server, none of the events in the Global.asax.cs file fire. (Only the Session_Start event has needed code in it, but I put code in Application_Start as well, just to see if it would fire - it did not).

Here's the Global.asax code:

```
<%@ Application CodeBehind="~\App_Code\Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Here's the Global.asax.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global
/// </summary>
public partial class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public Global()
    {

    // TODO: Add constructor logic here

    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown
    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Session["SessionSink"] = new SessionSink();             
            this.GetUserName();                              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = "An error occurred in Global.asax::Session_Start";
            ExceptionWriter ew = new ExceptionWriter();
            ew.LogError(msg, ex);
        }
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 

    }
}
```

Some notes based on other answers/discussions I've read:  Once published, PrecompiledApp.config DOES appear in the website's folder.  In addition, App_global.asax.compiled and App_global.asax.dll appear in the bin folder.

Anyone have any idea what the issue could be?  Why does this work from my local machine, but not once it's published to a server? Is there an IIS setting that I'm missing?

This is my first time using a asp.net "website", so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: what happens when u keep both .cs and .aspx file in the root folder and then publish? have u tried it? still the same behaviour?

Comment: @Athar Anis - yes when I put both global.asax and global.asax.cs in the root directory (and subsequently have to change CodeBehind to CodeFile in the global.asax file), the same behavior persists.  It works on my local machine, but not on the server.

Comment: that is strange.. just to remove my doubts can you plz change your director from CodeBehind="~\App_Code\Global.asax.cs" . replace "\" with "/"

Comment: also change the inherits to "inherits = "YOURNameSpace.Global" '

Comment: Just to make sure it's not a coding thing: What code did you test `Application_Start()` with?

Comment: @Athar Anis - I changed "\" to "/" as you requested.  No change in behavior.  Also, this website was not using namespaces originally, but I inserted one here just to test after reading your comment.  Same behavior - works on my local machine, not on the server.  By the way, thanks for you continued help.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell - I tested Application_Start by calling an ExceptionWriter class and writing a string ("Application Starts Now") to my ErrorLog.  Similar to what you see above in the "catch" portion in Session_Start (but not exactly).  I did the same thing in Session_Start (in the try portion) to ensure it wasn't my code.  As with everything else, the expected strings are written in my error log when running on my local machine.  But when running on the server, nothing is written to the error log (because I assume, global.asax.cs events are never fired).

Comment: @user2163572 no problem. I apologize for having been of much help, but still trying... I googled this issue and a lot of people have faced it appearantly. can you copy your global.asax on production and see if it hits any method?

Comment: Ok. Are you absolutely sure, your code isn't executed? I asked because I know some logging libraries won't fire an exception if something goes wrong. In case of an error they just do nothing. And perhaps you run into a database access issue which would be covered, so you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent that by not using the global.asax.cs at all; i.e. delete global.asax.cs and modify global.asax to

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.HttpApplication" %>
<script runat="server">
  public override void Init() {
    base.Init();
    var module = (SessionStateModule)Modules["Session"];
    module.Start += new EventHandler((sender, args) => {
        // create session sink here
    });
  }
</script>
```